# Unity - How can i implement wave count?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a tower defense game and I don`t have any idea how to implement a wave number count in script. Like my wave is killed the next wave should be numerotate 1/10, 2/10 etc. Can someone help me with the script?

Comment: Not trying to be irreverent in any capacity here, but this is a pretty basic thing to do. I would highly recommend taking a large step back and learning basic programming skills before going any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of TD tutorials. Even one by Unity itself:
https://learn.unity.com/project/tower-defense-template

But maybe this gives you an idea:

```
private int wave = 0;
public void nextWave()
{
    wave++;
    Debug.log("starting Wave " + wave + " / 20.");
}
```